# Don't show the message to all users? ( laravel )

Tags: laravel

I need to create to send a message to all new users registered on my website. I created a table called `messages` that admins can store (insert) the messages from the admin panel to this table and these messages are simply shown to all users with a `foreach`.

> I don't know if this the best way to do something like that!

Anyway, the problem is that when any new user register and open his dashboard he just found the old **messages**

This is the table :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U90P.png)

And this is the simple code for `foreach`

```
$msgForAll = Message::latest()->get();
```

I'm not sure how to display new messages to the users.

> Again the way I made this idea is wrong, I know that ):

Comment: I would recommend you provide more details of your current implementation, what is the difference between the result that you are getting now and you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eloquent's [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) spefically the `whereDate` queries in your case to get certain rows past or before date.

As an example relating to what you want to do, it can be along the lines of this:

```php
// Given that you are using Auth to get the user's data...

// Get messages that were created after the user's creation date
$messages = Message::whereDate('created_at','>',Auth::User()->created_at)->get();
```